# Handle 500 errors in JSON (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This JSON request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:jSONurl+'?orderID='+thisOrderID+'&variationID='+thisVariationID+'&quantity='+thisQuantity+'&callback=?',
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.response == 'success'){
            //show the tick. allow the booking to go through
            $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#tick'+thisVariationID).show();
        }else{
            //show the cross. Do not allow the booking to be made
            $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#cross'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#unableToReserveError').slideDown();
            //disable the form
            $('#OrderForm_OrderForm input').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

In certain circumstances will bring back a 500 error in the form of:

```
jQuery17205593111887289146_1338951277057({"message":"Availability exhausted","status":500});
```

This however is still useful to me and I need to be able to be able to handle this correctly.

For some reason though, when this 500 error is returned, my error function is not called and I just get a "NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error" error in firebug.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Is Firebug grabbing the error and halting things before jQuery can even see it?!

Comment: It's not, no. I've tried with firebug open and closed

Comment: Why do you have `async: false`? From the jQuery docs: "As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated."

Comment: I was executing the ajax call from within an $.each which was causing all kinds of issues. I have since reworked this to a better method and have not yet removed the async:false

Comment: Try it without the `async: false`. Just delete it; default is `true`. It may be that the code for calling the `error` function doesn't work for `async: false` due to a platform or browser bug.

Comment: Oh, and the issue you might have been seeing with `each` is that you can usually only have two AJAX transactions active at a time.

Comment: Have removed the async:false but still having the same issue unfortunately :(

Comment: Was this ever resolved?  I've got exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Did you try `statuscode` callback like

```
 $.ajax({
    statusCode: {
        500: function() {
          alert("Script exhausted");
        }
      }
   });
```

Comment: Vince recommended this too. I gave it a try but I am still getting the error and jQuery is not entering the function.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using POST you can use something like this:

```
$.post('account/check-notifications')
    .done(function(data) {
        // success function
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR){
        if(jqXHR.status==500 || jqXHR.status==0){
            // internal server error or internet connection broke  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you could catch it by adding this:

```
$.ajax({
    statusCode: {
      500: function() {
      alert("error");
       }
    },
    url:jSONurl+'?orderID='+thisOrderID+'&variationID='+thisVariationID+'&quantity='+thisQuantity+'&callback=?',
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.response == 'success'){
            //show the tick. allow the booking to go through
            $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#tick'+thisVariationID).show();
        }else{
            //show the cross. Do not allow the booking to be made
            $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#cross'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#unableToReserveError').slideDown();
            //disable the form
            $('#OrderForm_OrderForm input').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert('error');
    }
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives me the same 500 error in Firebug and doesn't enter the function

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [jqXHR Object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) docs. You could use the fail method to capture any errors.

Something like the following for your case:

```
$.post(jSONurl+'?orderID='+thisOrderID+'&variationID='+thisVariationID+'&quantity='+thisQuantity+'&callback=?')
.done(function(data){
        if (data.response == 'success'){
            //show the tick. allow the booking to go through
            $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#tick'+thisVariationID).show();
        }else{
            //show the cross. Do not allow the booking to be made
            $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#cross'+thisVariationID).hide();
            $('#unableToReserveError').slideDown();
            //disable the form
            $('#OrderForm_OrderForm input').attr('disabled','disabled');
        }
      }, "json")
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      alert("Got some error: " + errorThrown);
      });
```

I would also look into passing a json data string via post instead of attaching query variables:

```
$.post(jSONurl, $.toJSON({orderID: thisOrderID, variationID: thisVariationID, quantity: thisQuantity, callback: false}))
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed the dataType:json from the ajax call and I was able to catch the error. In these situations I do not need the content of the returned jSON luckily; only to know that there is an error being returned so this will suffice for now. Firebug still has a hissy fit but I am at least able to perform some actions when there is an error

```
$.ajax({
            url:'http://example.com/jsonservice/LiftieWeb/reserve?token=62e52d30e1aa70831c3f09780e8593f8&orderID='+thisOrderID+'&variationID='+reserveList+'&quantity='+thisQuantity+'&callback=?',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.response == 'Success'){
                    //show the tick. allow the booking to go through
                    $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
                    $('#tick'+thisVariationID).show();
                }else{
                    //show the cross. Do not allow the booking to be made
                    $('#loadingSML'+thisVariationID).hide();
                    $('#cross'+thisVariationID).hide();
                    $('#unableToReserveError').slideDown();
                    //disable the form
                    $('#OrderForm_OrderForm input').attr('disabled','disabled');
                }
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert('error');
            }
        })
```

Comment: This is a solution for you, but not a solution when we need JSON. Anyone has a real solution?